# Is Google Suggests like functionality possible in Java SWT?

Tags: java, autocomplete, combobox, swt

I want a drop down ComboBox like Google Search (i.e. when we type one letter then the elements starting with that letter are displayed). When the drop down list appears, then we can select one of word as our text box value.

Can I do this in SWT?

```
comboLabel.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        ArrayList<String> listElements = new ArrayList<String>();
        // on pressing down arrow list gets expanded i.e list drops down
        if(e.keyCode == 16777218)
        {
            comboLabel.setListVisible(true);
        }
        // if key pressed is only a number of charecter or space.
        else if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 122) || e.keyCode == 32)
        {
            // for removing all previously assigned labels
            comboLabel.remove(0,comboLabel.getItemCount()-1);
            listElements = labels.getLabels(comboLabel.getText());
        }

        for (int i=0; i<listElements.size();i++)
        {
            comboLabel.add(listElements.get(i),i);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is an auto-suggest ComboBox. As far as I know, it's not available in any Java standard widget library. However, a lot of people have built their own auto-suggest component. [Here's a good example](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2009/01/create-auto-suggest-jcombobox.html) with both source and an executable ".jnlp" extension.

Comment: The example you have provided is in Swings. I am not sure that can be done in SWT?

Comment: I think there are enough similarities between SWT and Swing that porting a small application such as this one is a feasible. If you are interested, here are some links for getting started: http://carfield.com.hk/document/java/tutorial/swing2swt.pdf and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650966/converting-an-awt-application-to-swt-jface.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything like that in SWT. Widgets in SWT have to correspond to native widgets on all platforms (generally), so implementing something like that would be difficult. One place to look for SWT Widgets that are new or experimental is the [Nebula](http://eclipse.org/nebula/) project, but I don't see it there either.

Comment: I have done it temporarily as following 1) For each key entered i am taking the string of the combo box and getting the results. 2) Remove all previously assigned list items of combo, 3) Add the new search results to combo. 4) SetListVisible property to 'true'. After 4) the list drops down and the focus is lost from thee combo's text field. So the difficulty in this approach is after entering each key the user has to reclick on the combo's text field to gain focus which is a very bad interface :( Any suggestions to improve this ?

Comment: Can you post your code as a snippet and maybe I can try it to see how it can be improved? Post it in the original question where it will get well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't be difficult. Just take a List where all your search strings are and then do some regex or indexOf stuff or Collections.binarySearch etc. Then draw a list down the text field with all the options. I can write you an example. What type of is the search data?